# How to change a href value if certain string is found

Tags: php

How to change a href value if a certain string is found

```
$string ='<a href="http://facebook.com/feelingblue">Facebook</a>'
```

if facebook is found on the href, replace to just facebook.com

Comment: `http://facebook.com/feelingblue` put manually or you are fetching it by `DB` .

Comment: Are you asking to how to change `$string ='<a href="facebook/feelingblue">Facebook</a>'` to `$string ='<a href="http://facebook.com/feelingblue">Facebook</a>'`?

Comment: anything which is there after facebook.com/* will get replaced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code,

```
$string ='<a href="http://facebook.com/feelingblue">Facebook</a>';
echo preg_replace('#http://facebook.com/([^"]+)#is', 'http://www.facebook.com', $string );
```

Thanks
Amit

Comment: this worked like a charm. follow up though, is possible that the http:// or www or https:// or https://www. is wildcard? so i dont have to specify #http://facebook.com/([^"]+)#is

Comment: also only for a href, there could other instance of the string

Comment: I know its not a good fix but i did it like this for now echo preg_replace('#href="http://facebook.com/([^"]+)#is', 'http://www.facebook.com', $string ); becuase there are other strings that contains facebook.com or other related

Comment: @user3240742 to replace anything before of after facebook string, this should work. $string ='<a href="http://photos.facebook.com/feelingblue">Facebook</a>';
echo preg_replace('#http://(.*?)facebook.com/([^"]+)#is', 'http://www.facebook.com', $string );

Comment: its a problem say if i had <p>http://facebook.com</p> <a href="photos.facebook.com/feelingblue">facebook</a>, its replace the text inside the <p></p>. i need to it be just the href

Answer (score 0):

Use RegExp, if you are searching from the whole document.

```
preg_replace_callback('(<a href=")([^"]+)(">([^<]+)</a>)', function($match){
    return $match[1] . "//example.com" . $match[3];
}, $html);
```

If you just want Facebook, you can add a check `if($match[4] === "Facebook")` and/or `if($match[2] === "http://facebook.com/feelingblue")`

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you fetching these values from `DB`

```
$url = 'http://facebook.com/feelingblue'; // this is the url you are getting

if (strpos($url , 'facebook') !== false) {
    $url = "https://facebook.com";
}

$string ='<a href="'.$url.'">Facebook</a>'
```

for more [information](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$string ='<a href="http://facebook.com/feelingblue">Facebook</a>';
if (strpos($string, 'facebook') !== false) {
    $facebookUrl = "http://www.facebook.com";
    $regEx = "/(?<=href=(\"|'))[^\"']+(?=(\"|'))/";
    $newUrl = preg_replace($regEx,$facebookUrl,$string);
}
echo $newUrl;
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You String is :-

```
$str ='<a href="http://facebook.com/feelingblue">Facebook</a>';
```

You may extract the href value by doing this :-

```
preg_match_all('~<a(.*?)href="([^"]+)"(.*?)>~', $str, $matches);
```

Removing  http://

```
$url = str_replace ('http://', '', $matches[2]);
```

Remove rest of the things after .com

```
$url = preg_replace ('/(\.com).*/','$1',$url);
```

Desired output would be

> facebook.com